# Indexing not working on update attribute of product in enterprise edition

Tags: magento

I am trying to update few attributes of product like special price but it is not getting updated on frontend when i am seeing my catalog_product_index_price_tmp table is also not updating.

Comment: have you did indexing ? and completed successfully ?
also check if you have added special price from and to date.

Comment: i am adding special price using update attribute mass action and i am not updating the special price to and from date.

Comment: Hi Chirag as per your comment i have tried with special price to and from date , it worked for first time but when i tried again it not worked moreover no entry is made in catalog_product_index_price_tmp table

Comment: catalog_product_index_price_tmp is only for store temporary data while indexing or when you save any product.
without "Special Price From Date" it will not work. just try to open product in which you are not getting special price and save without any changes. check it's works or not

Comment: Yes the price is changed to special price. but in the case of single save of product indexing is working that's why price is changed accordingly. Also my question is in case of update attribute mass action usually indexing works fine and attributes are updated but in my case it is not working